# Table in the table C# that i want to read one by one

Tags: c#

I want to read the content of a HTML Web page. And i'm trying to read all TABLE CONTENTS one by one...

Here is the part of what i'm getting problem

```
foreach (HtmlElement hrel in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table"))
{
    HtmlElementCollection coll2 = hrel.GetElementsByTagName("tr");

    if (coll2.Count > 3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(coll2[0].InnerText);
        MessageBox.Show(coll2[1].InnerText);
        MessageBox.Show(coll2[2].InnerText);
        MessageBox.Show(coll2[3].InnerText);
        MessageBox.Show(coll2[4].InnerText);
        MessageBox.Show(coll2[5].InnerText);
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
webBrowser1.Document.All["table"]
```